# What do I need to consider before promoting a Windows 2008 R2 Server to a Domain Controller?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'd like to move my DCs to Windows 2008 R2, what do I need to consider before running DCPROMO? I guess I have to extend the schema but will my XP clients still be able to logon?

I'm currently running 2003 DCs in native mode.

Comment: At which version is your present schema?

Comment: Hi, I'm on 2003 native mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be terse, but the following TechNet guide has all the info you need. This is the best source for gleaning which steps need to be taken in which order.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731188(WS.10).aspx